# Add Echo Effect in Media player in android

Tags: android, audio, echo, effect

How can I add echo effect in Media player in android. I searched a lot but did't find any answer. 
can anyone help me to implement that natively OR through any library.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this works for you :

[Live Audio Equalizer with echo effect](https://github.com/Cleveroad/WaveInApp)

Comment: Thanks for giving answer, but I want only echo effect without mixing any other audio effect. If possible then tell me some native approach like Equalizer and reverb.